# What scope to supply to get a refresh token from Stack Exchange?

Tags: support, api, security, authentication, oauth

In the process of implementing a OAuth app for Stack Exchange, I noticed that none of the approaches that conventionally work - supplying a `offline_access` scope, for example - result in the OAuth exchange exchanging a code for both an `access_token` and a `refresh_token`.

Additionally, the documentation makes no mention of a `refresh_token` (in fact, [/docs/authentication](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication) doesn't even contain the word 'refresh').

Is the expectation that the developer would always use `no_expiry` if they don't want to prompt the user to re-authenticate every day? Or is there a different request that I should be making?

URLs tried:

1. Valid request

> /oauth?response_type=code
>   &scope=read_inbox+private_info
>   &state=ey...AA
>   &client_id=1111
>   &redirect_uri=https://valid_redirect_url

- Works fine, but gives me a token that's only valid for a day.

2. Add a `refresh_token` to the scope.

> /oauth?response_type=code
>   &scope=read_inbox+private_info+**refresh_token**
>   &state=ey...AA
>   &client_id=1111
>   &redirect_uri=https://valid_redirect_url

- Scope error.

3. Add a `offline_access` to the scope.

> /oauth?response_type=code
>   &scope=read_inbox+private_info+**offline_access**
>   &state=ey...AA
>   &client_id=1111
>   &redirect_uri=https://valid_redirect_url

- Scope error.

4. Add a `grant_type=refresh_token` to the scope.

> /oauth?response_type=code
>   &scope=read_inbox+private_info
>   &state=ey...AA
>   &client_id=1111
>   &redirect_uri=https://valid_redirect_url
>   **&grant_type=refresh_token**

- No change in response.

What is the correct process to acquire a refresh token, or should I always specify the `no_expiry` scope?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disclaimer: I'm not a Stack Exchange employee, but I'm a frequent user of the API and moderator on [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/).

You've read the documentation, kudos for that, and as you saw, it does not have the ability to produce a refresh token. The official Stack Exchange mobile apps (now discontinued) didn't use it either; they all use the `no_expiry` scope.